# How to return the document data got from firestore using .get() to another function in JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that needs some data from firestore and I want to make another function that will get the data and return it to the function calling it

The code that I'm trying:

```
function getData(){
    var dataNeeded;
    let finalData = await db.collection("Trial").doc("trialDoc").get().then(doc => {
        dataNeeded = doc.data();
        console.log(dataNeeded);
        return dataNeeded;
    });
    return finalData;
}

function logic() {
dataRecieved = getData();
```

Here my `logic` function needs to use data that is received from the `getData` function

Any suggestions on how to get the data in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a promise

```
function getData() {
  return Firebase.firestore().collection("Trial").doc("trialDoc").get()
}

async function login() {
  const dataRecieved = await getData();
  // you can data using dataRecieved.data()
  // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to data from inside of `.then()`

```
async function getData(){
    return db.collection("Trial").doc("trialDoc").get().then(doc => {
        const dataNeeded = doc.data();
        return dataNeeded;
    });
}

//To get the data
getData().then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
}).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

You can use async-await syntax:

```
async function getData() {
  return (await db.collection("Trial").doc("trialDoc").get()).data()
}
```